# Get XML key value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I Have the following XML file:

```
<Configuration>
    <FilePath1>
        \\server\shared\stuff1
    </FilePath1>
    <FilePath2>
        \\server\shared\stuff2
    </FilePath2>
</Configuration>
```

and I need to get FilePath1 value (\\server\shared\stuff1). What is the easiest/elegant way to do that ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Using `XElement`

```
var filePath= Server.MapPath("LocationToYourFile/yourFile.xml");
XElement xElem = XElement.Load(filePath);
var e = xElem.Elements("FilePath1");
if (e.Any())
{
    var val = e.First().Value;
    //check val now
}
```